# Remaining RadioButtonList items lose their attributes if one item is removed

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

In ASP.NET 4.0 web application, if I have the following `<asp:RadioButtonList>` in my mark-up then all the alerts fire as expected when clicked, both before and after a post-back to the server...

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" id="rdoTest">
  <asp:ListItem Value="1" onclick="alert(1);">One</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="2" onclick="alert(2);">Two</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="3" onclick="alert(3);">Three</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

But if I remove one of the items in the code-behind, then the attribute is rendered on the initial page, but it is lost from the render on a post-back.

(This is a simplification of the original code, where the original code only removes the item in particular situations.  Otherwise I would simply remove the items from the mark-up, obviously.)

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    rdoTest.Items.Remove(rdoTest.Items.FindByValue("3"))
  End If
End Sub
```

The result of this is that the first 2 items are shown and the alert on the click works as expected.  But when a post-back happens, all the `onclick` attributes have been lost from those 2 items.

The only solution I've come up with is to manually reset them, such as this...

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    rdoTest.Items.Remove(rdoTest.Items.FindByValue("3"))
  Else
    For Each li as ListItem in rdoTest.Items
      li.Attributes("onclick") = String.Format("alert({0});", rdoTest.Items.IndexOf(li))
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

Why is ASP.NET losing the attributes on the post-back if the list is altered in the code-behind, but not if the list is left as it was in the mark-up?

Comment: Because you removed it. If you don't want to remove it, don't. Try hiding it instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Steve, but I feel you don't understand what I'm saying.  I realise I can't click on a non-existent item, that is not the problem. The problem is that the click of the **remaining** items is no longer there. (The removing of the item is only required in particular situations, but for ease of replication I've simply shown the code that will do just that.)

Comment: I did miss that. That is strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be your best bet:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210125132807/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091405-1.aspx

Short answer: ListItems are a .NET abstraction with complicated mappings to HTML elements. If you want to force certain attribute behavior, you may have to roll your own.

Comment: Thanks @welegan, but that article is for .NET 1.x. Things have moved on a bit since then

Comment: yeah, Microsoft has progressed to creating MVC and not updating webforms beyond patches :-P All kidding aside, even though it is an old article I believe it to still be true. The logic is sound: if `ListItem` can be rendered as `<option>` or `<input>` where only `<input>` allows for onclick as an attribute, then `ListItem` probably does not support it for all cases, even though it should for radio lists (which end up as `<input>`s versus drop down lists which end up as `<option>`s).